# Programmatically set an url parameter in gin context for testing purpose

Tags: go, testing, go-gin

I am writing some test suites for gin middlewares. I found a solution to test them without having to run a full router engine, by creating a gin context like this :

```golang
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
```

The goal is to test my function by calling :

```golang
MyMiddleware(c)

// Then I use c.MustGet() to check if every expected parameter has been transmitted to gin
// context, with correct values.
```

One of my middlewares relies on `c.Param()`. Is it possible to programatically set an Url param in gin (something like `c.SetParam(key, value)`) before calling the middleware ? This is only for test purpose so I don't mind non-optimized solutions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally figured it out by using IntelliJ to inspect the structure, I can just set it the raw way :

```golang
c.Params = []gin.Param{
    {
        Key: "id",
        Value: "first document",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to get the accepted answer to work due to the c.Request.URL being nil in some of my tests.

Instead, you can set the query like this:

```
c.Request.URL, _ = url.Parse("?id=mock")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution to adding URL/query parameters

```
result := httptest.NewRecorder()
context, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(result)
context.Request, _ = http.NewRequest("GET", "?page=2", nil)
```